# Retrieve Header value send to Stomp Message

Tags: angular, spring-boot, stomp

I have set up communication between my Spring boot service and an Angular 7 client using web-sockets (Stomp). Currently, I am able to push a message with headers from the spring boot application and receive it too. But I cannot access those headers in any format.

Is there any way I can read a Stomp Message Header?

I have tried to parse it as JSON but it fails too. I can Stringify the header but then ill have to do a lot of work in processing the string and getting the header value I need.

This is the relevant piece of code from the ts file

```
this.messagingService = new MessagingService(WEBSOCKET_URL, EXAMPLE_URL);

// Subscribe to its stream (to listen on messages)
this.messagingService.stream().subscribe((message: Message) => {
  this.messageHistory.unshift(message.body);
  console.log("all -> "+message);
  console.log("body -> "+message.body);
  console.log("headers -> "+JSON.stringify(message.headers));

});
```

This is the backend:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void sendMessage() {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("regno", "BCD123");
    template.convertAndSend(SENDING_URL, 1, headers);
}
```

The results I get after `JSON.Stringify` is

```
headers -> {"content-length":"1","message-id":"0-4","subscription":"sub-0","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","destination":"/topic/server-broadcaster","regno":"BCD123"}
```

Where "regno" is the header field I want to read.

Is there any way I can make this work without strings or any other suggestions as a workaround would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.